# Countability of a denumerable union of countable sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove the following denumerable$$\bigcup_ {n \in \Bbb N} \left\{\frac{n}{2^k} : k \in \Bbb N\right\}$$

I am supposed to use theorems from my book to prove this denumerable. There is a theorem in my book that states "If $\mathscr A$ is a denumerable family of countable sets, then $\bigcup_ {A \in \mathscr A}A$ is countable".

I am really hung up on the "syntax" in proving this. It is clear to be that the number of sets is countably infinite. ans that each individual sets for a fixed in is countable (also denmumerable). It seems like "drawing" the Cantor diagonalization for n/k would work, but doesn't really feel like a formal proof.  But creating a bijection seems trivial. Would I define $f: A_n \times \Bbb N$ given by $f(x)=A_x$ and prove this a bijection (surjective and 1-1)? What would this even look like? Next I assume I'd do something similar for a set for a fixed $n \in \Bbb N$. I.e. show a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\frac{n}{2^k}$. Like $f(k)=\frac{n}{2^k}$? Is the best way to do this? What would these functions look like? I feel like the first one would be super trivial to show is a bijection. Any help appreciated.

Comment: To apply the theorem you need to show (i) that for each $n$, the set $\{\frac{n}{2^k}\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable; to do this, you just need to give a bijection between the set and $\mathbb{N}$. Note that $n$ is **fixed**. And (ii) show that you have denumerably many sets in the union; this means establishing a bijection between the *index set*  of the union and $\mathbb{N}$. You don't need to do the "Cantor denationalization" (whatever that is).

Comment: what is $A_n$? and what is the range of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

You should apply the **countable union theorem** [ [check this if you are interested in a proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Countable_Union_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable) (note that this result depends on the axiom of countable choice, that is, that each countable set has a choice function)], that states that the union of a countable family of countable sets is also countable.

Note that in your case, for any fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$, you have that the set
$$\bigg\{ \frac{n}{2^{k}}:k\in\mathbb{N}\bigg\}$$
is clearly countable, for it is a sequence from the ordinal $\omega$ into $\mathbb{Q}$.
Since you are taking the union over the elements of $\omega$, the whole set 
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\bigg\{ \frac{n}{2^{k}}:k\in\mathbb{N}\bigg\}$$

Is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Your set is $$\bigcup_ {n \in \Bbb N} A_n$$

Where $$ A_n = \{\frac{n}{2^k} : k \in \Bbb N\}$$

All you need to do is  to show $A_n$ is countable for each $n\in \Bbb N$.

Note that for a fixed $n$, the function $f(k)= \frac {n}{2^k}$ is a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $A_n$

Now you can apply the theorem and you are done.

Comment: That's what I figured. I am confused on is the syntax for the bijection from $A_n \times \Bbb N$. Really the proof.

Comment: What about $f(A_n,k)=\frac {n}{2^k}$?